# input search no iphone

Tags: css, iphone

## Estou com a seguinte marcação:

```
    <form class="area-search" action="">
      <input name="search" type="search" placeholder="O QUE ESTA PROCURANDO?">
      <button>Buscar</button>
    </form>
```

No iphone/ipad está arredondando os cantos da input de busca. Tentei resetar usando `border-radius: 0 !important;` mas sem resultados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover os estilos do input no Chrome e Safari do iPhone basta usar:

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Para versões anteriores do iOS use:

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou agora.